# calling child page in controller in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I have created my master layout on a structure `views/layouts/approval_view.blade.php` is a child page and `views/layouts/travelApp.blade .php` ia a parent page.
I want to call this view page in controller.page doesn't found the route layouts/approval_view in controller page. I caught the error View

> [layouts.travelApp] not found. (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\testLaravel\TestTravel\resources\views\layouts\approval_view.blade.php)

```
public function index1(){

 // query
 return view('layouts/approval_view',['users'=>$users]);
 }
```

in approval view blade

```
@extends('layouts.travelApp')
```

Comment: Are both in `layouts` folder? Is the path correct?

Comment: yes boh in same folder

Comment: try: `@extends('travelApp')`

Comment: Are you sure you provided travelApp with the .blade.php extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've provided template name

views/layouts/travelApp.blade .php

I think, the space between blade and php might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('layouts.approval_view',['users'=>$users]);
```

NOT

```
return view('layouts/approval_view',['users'=>$users]);
```

Comment: caught InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [layouts.travelApp] not found.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.